# what's the meaning of the 0 in macro container_of?

Tags: c

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({      \
      const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);  \
      (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

The '0' in the macro container_of is completely unknown to me. Is it a syntax of c or some kind of gcc extension?

Hopefully, a simpler example to explain this '0'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually [implementation defined behaviour](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5). It casts an integer to a pointer. Note that this is **not** a [null pointer constant](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p3), as it is not cast to `void *`, but another type.

The cast effectively generates a pointer to an object of type `type` at address 0. As this is never accessed, this is not undefined behaviour. Reason is to generate a reference-object for the following `offsetof` and add some type-checking to the macro.

AFAIK, the macro is from the Linux kernel and heavily used (I use it myself in own code - very usefull, thanks guys!). It uses some gcc extension, but that's the block-expression (parethetised curly braces) and `typeof`, not the cast.

[Here](http://radek.io/2012/11/10/magical-container_of-macro/) is a detailed description what the macro does.

Comment: Btw, the second one of your links says "An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant", and the way I read that is that the cast is not required. A zero in "pointer context" is a null pointer constant.

Comment: @unwind: no, because in this context it is dereferenced, so you need a pointer first. try `0->member` and you will get a compiler error, because the `0` is actually not a pointer context, that (context) is just established by the cast. Pointer context would be e.g. an expression where coercion to pointer is done. As I wrote in a comment to your answer: this is at the edge of UB (not sure from which side, though) and one has to be precise. So

Comment: Aren't you claiming now that it's both dereferenced (in your comment) and that it's not, in your actual answer text?

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected my answer, you are right, thank you.

Comment: @Zaibis: this is no reason for DV, but you should have left a comment (and it was correct at the time of writing)! I should flag for mod!

Comment: I didn't start this. **I** did leave comments for DVs. From the help-center: ["When should I vote down? Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). No, you shall not just DV because you do not like an answer. And leaving a comment is a matter of politeness.